# Indonesian passport holder wishing to visit South Korea for tourism. Do I need a visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, south-korea, indonesian-citizens

I'm planning to visit South Korea next month. Short stay, only 5 days.

Do I still need a visa? I hold an Indonesian passport with a Malaysian visa (I live here currently).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Indonesian citizens do not benefit from visa exemptions, according to the website of the South Korean Ministry of Foreign Affairs.](http://www.mofa.go.kr/ENG/visa/application/index.jsp?menu=m_40_10) All non-exempt citizens must obtain a visa prior to travelling to South Korea.

In your case [you'll need a Ordinary Tourist C-3-9 visa](https://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=10101):

> [image: South Korea Ordinary Tourist C-3-9 visa description eligibility and documents required]

[You can use the online e-form here to begin your application.](https://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=10204)

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know how long it generally takes for the visa to be issued? Unfortunately, I already booked a ticket.

Comment: @flynzbr I have absolutely no idea. Your best bet is to contact your local Korean embassy and ask. FYI the way we say `thank you` on StackExchange sites is by upvoting posts you think are helpful and accepting the answer you think is right. I'm not saying you should vote me or accept my answer. I'd wait to verify if what I've said is true first.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this website](http://www.doyouneedvisa.com/visa/Indonesia/South%20Korea):

> Visa is not required for a maximum stay of 30 days if traveling as tourist.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong since I had this doubt myself. The way I understand [this](http://www.doyouneedvisa.com/visa/Indonesia/South%20Korea) is that the exemption is valid only for people travelling to/from Jeju: `Visa is not required for a maximum stay of 30 days if traveling as tourist, **if arriving at and departing from Jeju (CJU)**.` You are also missing that part of the quote.